# Как кроссбраузерно вызвать событие window.onresize на чистом Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Как мне кроссбраузерно вызвать событие `window.onresize` на чистом Javascript? 
Я нашел вот такой код:

```
var resizeEvent = window.document.createEvent('UIEvents'); 
resizeEvent.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, window, 0); 
window.dispatchEvent(resizeEvent);
```

Но `initUIEvent` является устаревший, поэтому нужно что-то другое.

Answer (score 2):

Ну да она как раз нужна для совместимости со старыми браузерами. На новых работает `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));`

Вот вам пример. Меняете размер окна или жмете на кнопку вызывается событие

> resize

. При этом показывается сообщение с соответствующим текстом.

```js
function click2() {
  if(typeof(Event) === 'function') {
  // modern browsers
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
  }else{
    // for IE and other old browsers
    // causes deprecation warning on modern browsers
    var evt = window.document.createEvent('UIEvents'); 
    evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, window, 0); 
    window.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
}

window.onresize = doALoadOfStuff;

function doALoadOfStuff() {
    //do a load of stuff
    alert("resize");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="click2();">event</button>
```

Код корректно работает в редакторе. Здесь на ресайз окна реакции может не быть.